# Get the specified decimal part having data only from the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from payments where amount = 0 order by id desc
```

I need to get the values which it has `0.5` part only.Could you tell me how to do that ?

e.g. 12,12.5,12.6,14.5

results data set can be have : `12.5,14.5` values data only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate amount to integer, subtract from original value and compare with 0.5

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
WHERE amount - CAST(amount AS INT) = 0.5
ORDER BY id DESC
```

OR:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM payments
 WHERE amount - FLOOR(amount) = 0.5
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Hacks way:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM payments
 WHERE PARSENAME(amount, 1)= 5
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

One more using modulo:

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
WHERE amount % 1 = 0.5
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: first one gives this error `Incorrect syntax near 'amount'.`

Comment: Do you use TSQL? I tested every in SQLFiddle and they work.

Answer (score 2):

you can find this way also

```
declare @temp table (val decimal(18,3))
insert into @temp values (0.5),(10.5),(20.8)

select * from @temp
where (val % 1) = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as accepted answer, just another thought:

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
WHERE FLOOR(amount) < CEILING(amount) -- or <>
ORDER BY id DESC
```

or

```
WHERE FLOOR(amount) + 1 = CEILING(amount)
```